# Bulk removal of N:N relationship in Dynamics CRM 2011

Tags: crm, bulk, entity-relationship

I have two entities with an N:N relationship.   For 1 entity instance I have over 500 relationships to the other entity. They are represented on the form for the 1st entity in a sub-grid. I need to remove these 500 relationships and rebuild them.

On the ribbon there is a button to remove 1-to-several selected relationships, but if I use it in this case, 500 links would take a long time to process manually.

Is there a more efficient alternative?

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a one time solution I suggest going into SQL server and deleting the relevant records from the bridge table (not supported but very efficient).

If you need a customer facing solution you could create a plugin that disassociates all records from a selected entity and have a "Disassociate All" button on the form or a workflow that triggers it.